# Unable to build bevy on windows rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, bevy

I am trying to use bevy game engine with rust on windows. I have `x86_64-mingw` installed on my machine.
I have setup the rust tool chain default to `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`. I put `bevy = "0.4.0"` under my dependencies in the `Cargo.toml`.
I tried `cargo build` and I get the following error

```bash
error: failed to run custom build command for `syn v1.0.63`

Caused by:
  could not execute process `C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\rust-game\target\debug\build\syn-a158346a8e8b6be7\build-script-build` (never executed)

Caused by:
  Access is denied. (os error 5)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

When I tried to compile in administrator mode `syn` compiled but another lib was giving error

```bash
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.24
   Compiling syn v1.0.63
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.124
   Compiling serde v1.0.124
error: failed to run custom build command for `proc-macro2 v1.0.24`

Caused by:
  could not execute process `C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\rust-game\target\debug\build\proc-macro2-a1d2a8cf734884f9\build-script-build` (never exe
cuted)

Caused by:
  Access is denied. (os error 5)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Edit:
My Antivirus was preventing it, and denying it access, so just turning my AV for sometime worked!

Comment: Have you tried using a console with admin privileges? The error is `Access is denied` which usually occurs when the OS denies access to some file/folder or resource.

Comment: @PauMAVA, yes as i mentioned in the details also `When I tried to compile in administrator mode syn compiled but another lib was giving error`, please read completely

Comment: Yes sorry, my brain skipped that part somehow. I've posted a fix that has worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried compiling a project that uses `bevy = "0.4.0"` and was able to build with the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` toolchain but not with `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`.

In my case, `bevy-glsl-to-spirv` is the crate that failed to build. On the [bevy book](https://bevyengine.org/learn/book/getting-started/setup/) is specified that you must have VS build tools 2019 installed. They do not explicitly say that you must use the `msvc` toolchain but as they require you to install VS build tools 2019 I guess you must compile the code using `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.

You can download VS build tools 2019 [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16).

Also make sure that you install the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` toolchain:

```
rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

Set this toolchain as the default toolchain.

```
rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

Finally, make sure the toolchain has been installed and set as the default toolchain:

```
rustup toolchain list
```

You should see:

```
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
```

Try to `cargo build` and it should work like a charm.

Comment: yes, i did do that later, but the problem was that my anti-virus was blocking cargo, thanks also. I referred [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2306)

Comment: Do you have Vulkan drivers installed?